# FIFO to communicate between threads

Tags: php, multithreading, queue, ipc, fifo

I've got a file with mail adresses to which I want to send an email.

I've splitted the jobs between

- one task which reads the file
- x others tasks that send emails

To communicate between the first task and the others, I thought that using FIFO (thanks to posix_mkfifo) would be a great idea, with one FIFO per "sending task", and cycle through them. Since I sometimes need to stop the script, I save the offset of the adresses file after each read (in the first task).

The problem is when I close the FIFO, the offset can be at the 500th row (so 500 adresses read and sent throughs FIFO) but maybe tasks have processed only 5 rows each.
How can I prevent the close of the FIFO on the writer side from stopping the other tasks to let them process their queues ?

Comment: You need another FIFO so the workers can let the master know when they've completed a task.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just a single offset in the file. Since the workers can process at different rates, you need to keep track of exactly which addresses have been processed.

Comment: I also had the idea to split the files into x files where x is the number of workers, so each worker has its file and offset. But it won't allow me to change the number of workers if I want, without having to do some manipulation on the files. If you have other ideas I'll take it !

Comment: Read the entire file into an array. Every time a worker confirms sending an email, remove the address from the array. When shutting down the script, save the array to the file.

Comment: can't do that since files contains milllions of entries.

i was able to resolve my problem by opening the fifo in read/write instead of only read on the second task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to resolve my problem by opening the fifo in read/write instead of only read on the second task